# Bases in function vector spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let

$$ {\prod}_{\ 2} := \{ f: [-1,1] \rightarrow R, f(x) \ \text{is polynomial with max degree of 2}\}$$ be a function space.

Now we have a subset base which is a subset of ${\prod}_{\ 2}$:

$$ B_2 = \{\phi_0 := x \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}x, \phi_1:=x \rightarrow -x^2+1, \phi_2:= x \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}x^2+ \frac{1}{2}x \} $$

I want to know how to show that $B_2$ is a base of $\prod_{2}$.

With linear "normal" vectors I could've easily solved this with the method of a determinant.

I got a hint that I need to solve this equation $\sum_{i=0}^2 a_i \phi_i = 0  \quad a_i \in R$ but I dont understand how this brings me further.

What steps do I have to take ?

Comment: just double checked no typo. can you elaborate why ?

Comment: uh, I'm not sure what I did wrong, can you edit the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Your equation remains true if you take $x=-1$, $x=0$ and $x=1$; so you get $a_0=a_1=a_2=0$.

Comment: so in other words, the only way for me to "get" 0 is to set $a_0  \ a_1 \ a_2$ to  0 ? which means it is independant ?

Comment: @zython: yes, that's it. And since $dim=3=Card(B_2)$,...